# Python calling base class using super vs static

Tags: python, inheritance, super, diamond-problem

Everywhere I look everyone keeps saying how great super() is. But, I'm leaning toward not using super() because it makes everything much more complicated than I would like. I've seen some popular examples of using super() but they never seem to show passing positional required arguments into the base class constructors.

I know of the diamond problem in Python, and super() prevents calling the base_base class twice. *(in this case Class A)*

Is it so bad that Class A's constructor is called twice? *(i.e., Case 2)*

Below is my code for the two cases.

Case 1: Using super()._ *init* _()

```
#abstractclass
class A(object):

    #abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, for_a, *args):
        self.val_a = for_a

#abstractclass
class B(A):

    #abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, for_a, for_b, for_c):
        super().__init__(for_a, for_c)
        self.val_b = for_b

#abstractclass
class C(A):

    #abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, for_a, for_c):
        super().__init__(for_a)
        self.val_c = for_c

class D(B, C):

    def __init__(self, for_a, for_b, for_c, for_d):
        super().__init__(for_a, for_b, for_c)
        self.val_d = for_d

class E(B):

    def __init__(self, for_a, for_b, for_e, *args):
        super().__init__(for_a, for_b, *args)
        self.val_e = for_e

newobject1 = D(1, 2, 3, 4)

newobject2 = E(10, 11, 12, 0)
```

Case 2: Static - Using base._ *init* _(self)

```
#abstractclass
class A(object):

    #abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, for_a):
        self.val_a = for_a

#abstractclass
class B(A):

    #abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, for_a, for_b):
        A.__init__(self, for_a)
        self.val_b = for_b

#abstractclass
class C(A):

    #abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, for_a, for_c):
        A.__init__(self, for_a)
        self.val_c = for_c

class D(B, C):

    def __init__(self, for_a, for_b, for_c, for_d):
        B.__init__(self, for_a, for_b)
        C.__init__(self, for_a, for_c)
        self.val_d = for_d

class E(B):

    def __init__(self, for_a, for_b, for_e):
        super().__init__(for_a, for_b)
        self.val_e = for_e

newobject1 = D(1, 2, 3, 4)

newobject2 = E(10, 11, 12)
```

Comment: `super` is not, however, just a drop-in replacement for a static call to the parent's base class. I would recommend reading both [Super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) and [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) to get a good feel for how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it so bad that Class A's constructor is called twice?

Absolutely, if the constructor is slow, or if it's non-idempotent, or if it acquires resources like file handles or database connections. In a more complex inheritance structure, you might also get constructors called 4 times, or 6, or as many times as there are paths up the inheritance graph from the child to the ancestor.

> I'm leaning toward not using super() because it makes everything much more complicated than I would like

It's not `super` making things complicated - it's multiple inheritance. Avoiding `super` in multiple inheritance just gives you different, probably-worse problems than `super`'s problems.

> I've seen some popular examples of using super() but they never seem to show passing positional required arguments into the base class constructors.

That's because positional constructor arguments don't work well with multiple inheritance. If you want to use a multiple inheritance structure like this, try making the arguments keyword-only and using `**kwargs` to pass through unrecognized arguments for other classes to handle. ["Python's super() considered super"](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) has some good advice for how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I looked into how to use **kwargs and I think they may fit my use case perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Idea is that `super()` is there to support [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) so that you could write your programs using [cooperative inheritance](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127).

Cooperative inheritance makes sense if you want to call your superclass' method, but you don't know specifically what superclass that will be - you only have an assumption that the method has the same signature as the method you're writing.

In your example, each `__init__` is different, so that's not a good use case for cooperative inheritance. Each class actually needs to know what `super` will target in order to call it properly. Therefore, you don't really get much of a benefit from `super` here.

---

Let's not forget: Multiple inheritance is recipe for a mess. There are conventions (sets of restrictions) that you can stick to, in order to have your code understandable and keep the spaghetti under control. One idea is using some base classes as mixins. Another idea is cooperative inheritance. Python has language constructs like `super` to support these, but if you're free to go outside of these boundaries. This comes with its own set of problems.